# Trying to add html w/ link using echo after else in php

Tags: php, html, hyperlink, echo

I have content only available to registered users - guests see an intro but if they click to read more are shown a message to login or register - I need to add a link to the registration page in the message they see.

Here is what I have tried:

```
if (!$user->guest) {
  echo $this->item->fulltext;  
}
else
echo '<h3><b>Please login or <a herf="/login/register">register</a> to view the entire article</b></h3>';
?>
```

My text shows correctly & the word register turns blue, but it is not linking. 
Please advise. Thank you in advance.

Comment: You have a typo in your `href`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you can tell me what a `herf` is, I'll wonder myself.

It's spelled `href` not `herf`.

=>

```
<a href="/login/register">register</a>
```

Comment: Duh! Thank you for pointing out the obvious, I can't type ;) I fixed the typo & it is working now.

Comment: @ahmet you can ask the w3c if they're willing to change it :-P

Comment: YES! perfect. Please implement this now.